# Which are the good tools to develop angular js applications?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs. Are there any good tools available which will assist me in coding angularjs apps? I am looking for a tool which will provide auto suggestions, syntax error highlighters etc for javascript.

Answer (score 5):

There is for me two editors really usefull, first one is sublimeText :

http://www.sublimetext.com/

angularjs plugin and installation for sublime text

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/08/30/using-the-angularjs-package-for-sublime-text.aspx

The second one is intellij idea

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: Thank u. To use Sublime Text we have to purchase the license. I was looking for opensource/free tool like this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [JetBrains Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).

Also, check out [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), and [Bower](http://bower.io/).